# Using sass-lint within npm script leads to error

Tags: angularjs, scss-lint, sass-lint

I'm putting together an app using angular-cli. I'm going to write my styles in SCSS and as such I want to have linting available for my SCSS files. Node-sass is already installed when using angular-cli to create an app and I've install [sass-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-lint) locally.

I can now run the linting command successfully from the command line:

```
./node_modules/.bin/sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q
```

And this gives me a list of errors and warnings:

```
src/app/app.component.scss
  2:3   error    Expected `background-color`, found `color`                                     property-sort-order
  2:10  warning  Color 'red' should be written in its hexadecimal form #ff0000               no-color-keywords
  2:10  warning  Color literals such as 'red' should only be used in variable declarations   no-color-literals
  3:3   error    Expected `color`, found `background-color`                                  property-sort-order
  3:21  warning  Color 'blue' should be written in its hexadecimal form #0000ff              no-color-keywords
  3:21  warning  Color literals such as 'blue' should only be used in variable declarations  no-color-literals
```

However, when I add this comand as an NPM script in `package.json` it produces an error, even though it also gives me the result of the linting:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "scsslint": "./node_modules/.bin/sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q"
    }
    ...
}
```

Result output:

```
> starter@0.0.0 scsslint /home/brian/Projects/tutorials/angular2/starter
> sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q


src/app/app.component.scss
  2:3   error    Expected `background-color`, found `color`                                  property-sort-order
  2:10  warning  Color 'red' should be written in its hexadecimal form #ff0000               no-color-keywords
  2:10  warning  Color literals such as 'red' should only be used in variable declarations   no-color-literals
  3:3   error    Expected `color`, found `background-color`                                  property-sort-order
  3:21  warning  Color 'blue' should be written in its hexadecimal form #0000ff              no-color-keywords
  3:21  warning  Color literals such as 'blue' should only be used in variable declarations  no-color-literals

✖ 6 problems (2 errors, 4 warnings)


npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/brian/.npm-packages/bin/npm" "run" "scsslint"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! starter@0.0.0 scsslint: `sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the starter@0.0.0 scsslint script 'sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/brian/.npm/_logs/2017-03-14T11_52_04_406Z-debug.log
```

Here is the resulting log output from NPM:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/brian/.npm-packages/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'scsslint' ]
2 info using npm@4.3.0
3 info using node@v6.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prescsslint', 'scsslint', 'postscsslint' ]
5 info lifecycle starter@0.0.0~prescsslint: starter@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle starter@0.0.0~prescsslint: no script for prescsslint, continuing
7 info lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: starter@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: PATH: /home/brian/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/brian/Projects/tutorials/angular2/starter/node_modules/.bin:/home/brian/.npm-packages/bin:/home/brian/bin:/home/brian/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
10 verbose lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: CWD: /home/brian/Projects/tutorials/angular2/starter
11 silly lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: Args: [ '-c', 'sass-lint \'src/**/*.scss\' -v -q' ]
12 silly lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle starter@0.0.0~scsslint: Failed to exec scsslint script
14 verbose stack Error: starter@0.0.0 scsslint: `sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/brian/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/brian/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid starter@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/brian/Projects/tutorials/angular2/starter
17 error Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/brian/.npm-packages/bin/npm" "run" "scsslint"
19 error node v6.9.4
20 error npm  v4.3.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error starter@0.0.0 scsslint: `sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the starter@0.0.0 scsslint script 'sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the starter package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs starter
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls starter
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I can't work out how to find what is causing this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The error was most likely triggered by the Sass linter *errors* captured in the code.

Every time this happens `sass-lint` sets the exit code to 1 (error) which, in turn, gets picked up by the Node.js environment - hence all these `ERR` log entries.

If you'd only had linter `warnings`, the exit code would have been 0 (or "success") and that issue would have not cropped up.